# Use SublimeText to delete all log entries except IPs

Tags: regex, logging, replace, sublimetext2, editing

I have a log file in Sublime Text, with entries that look like the following:

`51.255.65.70 - - [11/Apr/2016:21:55:43 +0200] "GET URL HTTP/1.1" 200 1537`

How can I remove everything except the IPs? The file is too large for me to do it manually. Thank you.

Comment: If you can find the pattern to keep, you can simply select it with regex, then _invert_ the selection and click "enter". You'll have one result per line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>
Make sure regex is enabled, icon looks like <kbd>.*</kbd>.

Replace `^([^\s]+).*$`with `\1`

Answer (score 0):

An IP looks like `((?:\d{1,3}\.?){4})`, so find and replace `((?:\d{1,3}\.?){4}).*` with `\1`.

If you're only going to want IPs that begin a line, begin the search with a `^` (e.g. `^((?:\d{1,3}\.?){4}).*`)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this pattern for IP-adresses:

```
\b(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b
```

However, according to [RegEx.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), this is the ultimate pattern:

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

But I think the first one will do just fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the regex

```
^([.\d]+).+
```

... and replace this with `$1`.
See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nR9jD0/1).